# Looking for a good book for Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can you recommend me book to Google App Engine in Python?
English/French books are both accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Programming Google App Engine: Build and Run Scalable Web Apps on Google's Infrastructure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652272X) is a pretty good book that talks about both the Java and Python APIs. Google also has good [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) tutorial that I thought was pretty good.

Good luck.

Comment: the getting startted tuturial is not enought I know it by hearth... thank you

Answer (score 2):

I come back to this question after sereval searches.
I rode Programming Google App Engine by Dan Sanderson and Using Google App Engine by Charles Severance (both edited O'Reilly and Google Press) and they are pretty good.
I recommend it for basic usage.

Answer (score 1):

[Head First Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449382673) covers the basics of GAE and gets you running in python.

Answer (score 1):

[Using Google App Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680069X)
By: Charles Severance

[Python Web Development with Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132356139)®
By: Jeff Forcier; Paul Bissex; Wesley Chun

and the books recommended above should give you a good base.